# can't type alphabet r in vs code it shows" command 'extension.CustomCompileRun' not found"

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, compiler-construction

i tried reinstalling power shell , vs code , cmd but i am not able to type alphabet "r" in "vs-code". when i i type "r" it shows "command 'extension.CustomCompileRun' not found" i can copy and paste the alphabet "r"
it works that time but not when i type ALPHABET "R".

Comment: check your key bindings file, try to use the key bind debugging